# Finding external shares using Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I currently have an application that will search document acls and report back on any external sharing.  Since the deprecation of the document list api I would like to covert this application to Google Drive but since the user email address is no longer present in the Permission object returned from Drive is there any way to detect these shares?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Match the username you get from the Owner field to the users in your directory using the profile api https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/. If the user is not in the directory, the user is external.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To comment on this answer, the owner field would be the owner of the Drive File, which should be within the domain.  I am referring to finding Permission objects that are external to the domain.  Also, I would like to add a bit of additional information.  My application also gives the ability to share to specific domains and strip shares that are not on this list.  As an example allow sharing to @google.com domains but no others.  Would this functionality be able to be reproduced using Drive?

Comment: For now I'd say this is not possible. Using the OAuth2 playground, I looked into a file share with me from another domain (and a file I shared outside my domain) and could not find any indication that the permissions were outside of my domain. So I don't think you can use the API just now to identify the domain associated with a permission.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use 'domain' field in permission to define if your document is shared with an external user or not. You have to campare this field with the domain that you own.

Thanks,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's not a critique or a request, it's an answer to his request. I don't understand why did you delete my answer.